# In which cases can viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) method will not be called even that viewDidLoad() is already called?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

My view life cycle:

`viewDidLoad()` called normally, but `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` is not called but it appears in UI normally:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // some business
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // some business
}
```

Comment: Check with breakpoints on `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

Comment: How are you showing this viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed.

Comment: the viewcontroller added as child viewController

Comment: @markonazmy, could you post (in your question) the *full* code you are using for making this a child VC? I've done this and have no issues - maybe there's a problem there. For instance, are you *both* making (1) the VC be a child controller and (2) adding it's view to the parent view?